# I want to show another second tag on the click of first anchor tag and hide the first anchor tag

Tags: javascript, anchor

I have five anchor tags. I want to display second anchor tag on click of first anchor tag and hide it self and further when click on second anchor tag show third anchor tag and hide itself and so on.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="btn0" onclick='showBtn1()'  class="w-auto rounded-pill bg-transparent border px-3 py-2 text-decoration-none text-reset suggestion"><?php print(strval($suggestions[0])); ?></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="btn1"  style="display:none" class="w-auto rounded-pill bg-transparent border px-3 py-2 text-decoration-none text-reset suggestion"><?php print(strval($suggestions[1])); ?></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="btn2"  style="display:none" class="w-auto rounded-pill bg-transparent border px-3 py-2 text-decoration-none text-reset suggestion"><?php print(strval($suggestions[2])); ?></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="btn3"  style="display:none" class="w-auto rounded-pill bg-transparent border px-3 py-2 text-decoration-none text-reset suggestion"><?php print(strval($suggestions[3])); ?></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="btn4"  style="display:none" class="w-auto rounded-pill bg-transparent border px-3 py-2 text-decoration-none text-reset suggestion"><?php print(strval($suggestions[4])); ?></a>
                   

<script>
function showBtn1()
    {
        var btn0 = document.getElementById('btn0');
        var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
        var btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');
        var btn3 = document.getElementById('btn3');
        var btn4 = document.getElementById('btn4');

        if(btn1.style.display == 'none')
        {
            btn1.style.display = 'initial';
            btn0.style.display = 'none';
            btn2.style.display = 'none';
            btn3.style.display = 'none';
            btn4.style.display = 'none';
        }
        else
        {
            btn1.style.display = 'none';
            btn0.style.display = 'none';
            btn2.style.display = 'none';
            btn3.style.display = 'none';
            btn4.style.display = 'none';
        }
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use ID attributes and weird concatenation to accomplish your stated goal. You could bind a single event listener to the parent element that contains the `a` elements and use the [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) property to identify which `a` element invoked the event handler and find that elements index within the [nodelist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). With that index value you can use simple arithmetic to find the next element or reset index to beginning. The following has, as the original, 5 hyperlinks but could be scaled to any number without modification.

```js
const d=document;
const cn='active';
const parent=d.querySelector('#parent');

// Find all "a" elements and convert nodelist to Array
// Below uses the "spread syntax" ( or "Splat" operator )
const col=[...parent.querySelectorAll('a')];

// Delegated event listener bound to a suitable Parent element
parent.addEventListener('click',e=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  
  // ensure all elements are hidden
  col.forEach(a=>a.classList.remove(cn));
  
  // Where is this "a" in the array?
  let i=col.indexOf( e.target );
  
  // increment index to find next "a" element
  i++;
  
  // reset index if we exceed array length
  if( i >= col.length )i=0;
  
  // show the next element
  col[i].classList.add(cn);
});
```

```css
#parent a{display:none}
#parent .active{display:block!important}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
  <a href='#' class="active w-auto rounded-pill bg-transparent border px-3 py-2 text-decoration-none text-reset suggestion">link #1</a>
  <a href='#' class="w-auto rounded-pill bg-transparent border px-3 py-2 text-decoration-none text-reset suggestion">link #2</a>
  <a href='#' class="w-auto rounded-pill bg-transparent border px-3 py-2 text-decoration-none text-reset suggestion">link #3</a>
  <a href='#' class="w-auto rounded-pill bg-transparent border px-3 py-2 text-decoration-none text-reset suggestion">link #4</a>
  <a href='#' class="w-auto rounded-pill bg-transparent border px-3 py-2 text-decoration-none text-reset suggestion">link #5</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm a newbie so could you explain in details to me

Comment: The comments through the code should explain what is happening at each stage. Is there some part in particular that is not clear?

Comment: find all a elements and covert nl to array

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a static nodelist ( a collection of DOM nodes and is similar to an array but NOT an array  ) but does not provide all of the methods available to an array. Using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (also known as the "Splat Operator" ) you can quickly convert a nodelist to an array so that you can access array methods/properties - in this case `length`

Comment: the second anchor tag just appears for a bit and disappear.. and at end all the anchor tags are displaying.

Comment: What browser are you using? In Chrome the above snippet seems to work OK as far as I understand the question

Comment: I'm using chrome only.

Comment: If the problem you describe happens on your site/test system and NOT in the above snippet it suggests that other CSS/Javascript might be interfering and causing the problem. Can you confirm where this problem happens for you?

Comment: It's working fine on simple page but not working with the page I want to make it work

Comment: is there any route where I can show you complete code???

Comment: It depends on how large the "complete code" is -- pastebin is an option but my advice would be to `comment out` (ie:negate) the CSS and work through by re-enabling peices of the css until you find which piece is causing the issue and then resolve that.

Comment: Thanks for the help! another js was interfering the code. Thanks a lot !

Comment: I want to show value number 3,4,5 together. What can I do?

Comment: That seems like a wholly different question. Perhaps accept/close this question and ask another with updated codebase and explain new question?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```js
<script>
   function showBtn(ix) {
        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            document.getElementById('btn' + i).style.display = 'none';
        }
        document.getElementById('btn' + ix).style.display = 'initial';
   }
</script>
```

In the buttons use `onclick='showBtn(1 up to 5)'`

Have fun learning. Read a little about coding principles.

Comment: still all the anchor display on the click of the first anchor tag

Comment: Is your script in a js file or is it on the same page as the buttons? If it's in a js file, the browser caches your previous code, so use Ctrl+F5 to reload the page (it forces cached items to reload too).

Comment: Thanks for the help! another js was interfering the code. Thanks a lot !